# Init a const var in a struct after the struct variable is created

Tags: c

I have a c struct that has a const variable.

```
typedef struct {
u32 status;
const u32 dir_search_idx;} FS_OBJ;
```

What I would like to do is init the const variable in a function once I have created the struct object. I guess I want to do something similar to what a constructor would do in c++. Is it possible to do something similar in c? Thanks

Comment: In C++ constructors are called when an object is being created. They are not called for an already created object. So you can initialize the data member of the structure when an object of the structure type is being created.

Comment: It's not `const` if you change it after you create it. So remove the `const` keyword.

Comment: I need the var to be a const as I want the code to be optimized. I just need a way to set the value of the const once

Comment: Does the `const` have to be initialized *after* creating the struct?

Comment: Then you have to set it when you create it. So you call a function that returns the search index, and then create the struct using the search index as an initializer.

Comment: Do you think the code in the question creates a structure object? It does not; it only defines a type. You can assign values to the members of a structure object when you create the structure object using initializers as in `FS_OBJ foo = { 3, 4 };` to set the first and second members to 3 and 4 or `FS_OBJ foo = { .status = 3, .dir_search_idx = 4 };` to set the members named `status` and `dir_search_idx` to 3 and 4, respectively. After the definition of the actual object, it is undefined behavior to attempt to change a `const` member.

Comment: `I need the var to be a const as I want the code to be optimized` That's a questionable goal. Use `const` when you don't want to modify the data, profile the code when you want it optimized. `const` (pointers?) may have an effect on performance, but have you really measured that using `const` does have affect on performance? See rule 1 in [rules of optimization](https://wiki.c2.com/?RulesOfOptimizationClub). Then see rule 2.

Comment: I want to setup the var when the program first starts. I then dont want to modify it. Wont the compiler just insert the value where the var is used?

Comment: @user14104726  "I want to setup the var when the program first starts. " --> OK, then `int main() { FS_OBJ obj = {.dir_seach_idx = some_function() }; ...`

Answer (score 3):

This should work perfectly fine if you are using C99 or newer and want to initialize the `const` variable *when* creating the struct:

```
FS_OBJ obj = { .status = /* something */, .dir_seach_idx = /* something */ };
```

You can't modify the `const` variable *after* creating the struct. Then you would have to remove the `const` keyword as mentioned by [user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386109/user3386109) in the comments.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It seems like it's not of importance for him to initialize the variable *after* creating the struct, because he says *"I just need a way to set the value of the const once"* in the comments.

Comment: Thanks but I dont want to have to init the values when I create it. I need to create it then be able to set the values from a function. I need to get some other values before I can set the const var.

Comment: `I dont want to have to init the values when I create it` then don't use `const`.

Comment: I want the var to be const as I want the compiler to optimize the code. Its being used in a micro controller

Comment: @user14104726 "I need to create it then be able to set the values from a function" --> then use `FS_OBJ obj = {.dir_seach_idx = some_function() };`.  Call the function and use its result to initialize `obj`.

Comment: Please don't. `const` is not for that. `const` means that you can't later modify the data - that you can't initialize it later.  Please write readable and well structured code instead.

Comment: `obj->dir_search_idx = /* something */` will not work - `dir_search_idx` is const.

Comment: @KamilCuk Even if I only allocate the memory for the `struct`? If that's the case, I will rollback the edit.

Comment: `const` means you can't modify the memory __via this handle__. You can't modify the memory via `obj->dir_search_idx`. You can cast constness away, like `*(u32*)&obj->dir_search_idx =`

Comment: @KamilCuk Okay thanks I have now rolled back the edit so the answer should be correct now.

Comment: @KamilCuk Using *(u32*)&obj->dir_search_idx = seems to work. Thanks

Comment: Casting away `const` leads to UB if the object is unmodifiable.

Comment: @KamilCuk: You can safely remove `const` via a cast if the original object is modifiable. If an object was **defined** with `const`, it is not modifiable in this sense. In that case, the behavior of attempting to modify the object with a non-`const` lvalue is not defined by the C standard, per C 6.7.3 7: “If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined…”

Answer (score 0):

I think `const` is not the right tool for what you are looking for. You can put data (`structs`) and behavior (`functions`) in a *.c file and provide public functions in the corresponding header file. This way you can mimic the equivalent c++ code that you want and hide the data and of course, you can define a constructor. A great book that might help is [The GLib/GTK+ Development Platform](https://people.gnome.org/%7Eswilmet/glib-gtk-book/). In chapter 3 you can find a good introduction to Semi-Object-Oriented Programming in C.
Here is a possible implementation, not necessarily the best one:

/src/main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "point.h"

int main()
{
    Point *p1 = init(6, 7);
    printf("%d\n", getX(p1));
    printf("%d\n", getY(p1));

    Point *p2 = init(12, 14);
    printf("%d\n", getX(p2));
    printf("%d\n", getY(p2));
    
    setX(p2, 16);
    printf("%d\n", getX(p2));
    setY(p2, 16); /* error; we want y to initialize once and remain constant. Also accessing y with p2->y is an error too. */
    printf("%d\n", getY(p2)); /* getY is ok */
    
    freep(p1);
    freep(p2);
}
```

/src/point.h

```
typedef struct _Point Point;

Point *init(int, int);
int getX(Point *);
void setX(Point *, int);
int getY(Point *);
void freep(Point *);
```

/src/point.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "point.h"

struct _Point{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Point *init(int x, int y)
{
    Point *temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(Point));
    temp->x = x;
    temp->y = y;
    
    return temp;
}

int getX(Point *p)
{
    return p->x;
}

void setX(Point *p, int x)
{
    p->x = x;
}

int getY(Point *p)
{
    return p->y;
}

void freep(Point *p)
{
    free(p);
}
```

Furthermore, if we need a private method in our class, we do not provide a declaration of it in the header and also we use `static` to restrict its access within the class's file.